# How to use regex to select a row and a fixed number of rows following a row containing a specific substring in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

**Problem**:
I have a pandas dataframe that I am trying to extract specific rows from. The rows I'm interested in are those that contain a date, and the row immediately following the row with a date. Importantly, I want to move the information from the line that follows the date to a new column in the row that contains the date. By doing this, I will have "one persons" information on the same line. To be clear, I want to find the rows containing dates, and move the information from the row following the date to the row that contained the date in a new column.

**From this:**

```
    Col0  Col1       Col2      Col3   Col4    Col5
    0     NaN        NaN       NaN    NaN     NaN
    1     *1/23/20   Joe G     USA    NaN     G5 paper
    2     NaN        get_me    NaN    NaN     NaN
    3     +1/5/20    Frank F   CAN    NaN     F4 Paper
    4     NaN        get_me_2  NaN    NaN     NaN
```

**To this:**

```
    Col0  Col1     Col2     Col3   Col4     Col5      Col6(New column)
    0     1/23/20  Joe G     USA    NaN     G5 paper      get_me
    1     1/5/20  Frank F   CAN    NaN     F4 paper      get_me_2
```

**Stated another way**: I'm basically just trying to get all the date rows to grab the information on the next line so for each date there is a person and then all of their information is on one line. It is okay if all the information in the second line is in the same column in the row preceding it.

**Things to keep in mind**: There are often (but not always) a "*" or "+" character preceding the dates (e.g., **1/12/12 or +5/5/20). I tried first to match rows that contain a date. There is only one of these, but one date has a name "attached" (e.g. *1/1/20Dev). I would like to know if the column containing the date (dates always are in same column) has any other "crap" in it. This would be icing on the cake, but that is not the core issue I'm having.

There is usually only one item in the second row, but if there are more, I can deal with those later. I just need all the "persons" information on the same line. I'm reading the original data in through a PDF and I'm trying to clean it up.

**What I've tried**: I began by trying to match strings that contain a "date-like" string. In reality these will all be in a pandas dataframe row but it does seem like regex would be suitable to get just the rows containing dates (for which I can get the row immediately after and move its contents onto the row containing the date)

```
    import re
    search_in = '*1/4/13'
    wanted_regex = r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)'
    match = re.search(wanted_regex, search_in)
    match.group(1)
```

**output**  : '1/4/13'

- **summary**: good start but need to somehow iterate over each row containing these, and move information from the row following it to the row containing the date.

**A good example**:

```
    def regex_filter(myregex, val):
        if val:
            mo = re.search(myregex,val)
            if mo:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    df_filtered = 
    df[df['col'].apply(regex_filter)]
```

**What gives?** Above is a good example of what I believe I'm trying to do, but I'm really stumped here and dont really know how I should control where in the code to get the next row and move it up.I see a lot of similar problems but I can't determine whether I should be grouping, filtering, querying...? If you could offer a brief theory on why you choose what you chose to solve this problem it would be really helpful for how to think about this in the future. This is where I'm at now and could really use some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Kevin, first off. Well documented question. Kudos on having your first question clearly written. Suggestions: can you please post clear text data instead of links. The problem with links is it gets broken over time. Also it makes it difficult to copy the data over to try out the solution.

Comment: @JoeFerndz Sorry about that. I keep trying to post over the textual information and every time I press enter it keeps submitting the question. I'm trying to figure out how to get it in text over here. My apologies for this and any notifications you're receiving that must be annoying my fault not trying to

Comment: @JoeFerndz thanks again so much for your comment and help. If you get around to it, I think I have been able to represent the problem now with text data. My bad on the broken links and thanks for pointing that out for me in the future.

Comment: I see the test data. Will work on this later tonight when I am back from the family event

Comment: A few folks in the community like jazrel, prune, thomas, ben_yo to name a few are good at solving this too

Comment: Your first row has all NaNs except Col0. Assume that row can easily be deleted. Is there any significance to Col0 ?

Comment: No significance to column 0. The way you handled it in the answer was perfect and helpful (e.g. df=df.iloc[1:]) to skip the first row. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Chris for getting this done.

Kevin, there are a few ways to go about this. I will do it the easiest way. I am also making some assumptions. They are:

1. Col0 is just a sequence from 0 thru length of dataframe - 1
2. Any row that has NaN (null values) in all columns except Col0 can be excluded
3. Every alternate row Col2 in the dataframe can be assigned to Col6
4. The only information in alternate rows in the dataframe is Col6 value
5. Once Col6 assignment is done, we can discard alternate rows

If all the above assumptions are true, then the below code will work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

c = ['Col0','Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5']

d = [[0,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [1,'*1/23/20','Joe G','USA',np.NaN,'G5 paper'],
    [2,np.NaN,'get_me',np.NaN,np.NaN, np.NaN],
    [3,'+1/5/20','Frank F','CAN',np.NaN,'F4 Paper'],
    [4,np.NaN,'get_me_2',np.NaN,np.NaN, np.NaN]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
print (df)

#Step 1:remove all row that has only NaNs (ignore Col0)
#See bottom of answer section for alternate ways to remove first row (if assumption 2 is invalid
df = df.dropna(subset = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'],how='all',)

#Step 2: Col 1 : remove all leading and trailing characters from the date
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.extract('(\d+/\d+/\d+)', expand=False)

#Step 3: Col 6 will contain value of Col2 (next row)
df['Col6'] = df['Col2'].shift(-1)

#Step 4: There is no need for all even rows in the dataframe anymore. Make then NaNs
df[1::2] = np.NaN

#Step 5: Delete all even rows as they have NaNs (thanks to Step 4)
df = df.dropna(how='all',)

#Step 6: Reset Col0 value to start from 1 and increment by 1. Use np.arange(df.shape[0]) is quickest
df['Col0'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])

#Step 7: Reset Index for the dataframe
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#Step 8: Voila!!! We now have the final result dataframe. print the result
print (df)
```

The output of this is as follows:

**Original dataframe:**

```
   Col0      Col1      Col2 Col3  Col4      Col5
0     0       NaN       NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN
1     1  *1/23/20     Joe G  USA   NaN  G5 paper
2     2       NaN    get_me  NaN   NaN       NaN
3     3   +1/5/20   Frank F  CAN   NaN  F4 Paper
4     4       NaN  get_me_2  NaN   NaN       NaN

Updated dataframe:

   Col0     Col1     Col2 Col3  Col4      Col5      Col6
0     0  1/23/20    Joe G  USA   NaN  G5 paper    get_me
1     1   1/5/20  Frank F  CAN   NaN  F4 Paper  get_me_2
```

**Alternate ways to solve for first row in the dataframe**

You can use below approach if assumption 2 is incorrect and you want to eliminate only row 1.

Looks like your first row is really not useful and you can drop it.

To do so, here are a few simple ways to solve it.

Option 1: best option

```
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Option 2: round about still a good option

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Col0')] = np.NaN

#alternate df.iloc[0,0] = np.NaN
df = df.dropna(subset = ['Col0'],thresh=1)
```

This will remove the first row from the dataframe

Comment: Such a phenomenal answer @Joe Ferndz. You are a class act. Thank you so much. You both answered my questions in ways that are useful for many other problems outside this one. I’m really grateful for your time on this.

Answer (score 2):

First off, start with `pandas.Series.str.extract` to get the date-like string:

```
s = df["Col1"].str.extract("(\d+/\d+/\d+)", expand=False)
```

Then use `pandas.to_datetime` to actually filter out valid dates:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(s, dayfirst=True, errors="coerce")
# errors="coerce" to transform invalid strings
```

which so far yields:

```
0          NaT
1   2020-01-23
2          NaT
3   2020-05-01
4          NaT
Name: Col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then use `pandas.Series.ffill` with `limit==1` to grab the valid date and **right next row**:

```
df["Col1"] = s.ffill(limit=1)
df = df.dropna(subset=["Col1"])
print(df)
```

So we have desired rows and their next row:

```
   Col0       Col1      Col2 Col3  Col4      Col5
1     1 2020-01-23     Joe G  USA   NaN  G5 paper
2     2 2020-01-23    get_me  NaN   NaN       NaN
3     3 2020-05-01   Frank F  CAN   NaN  F4 Paper
4     4 2020-05-01  get_me_2  NaN   NaN       NaN
```

Finally, use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` to iterate and unmelt `Col2` only:

```
dfs = []
for k,d in df.groupby("Col1"):
    dfs.append(d.assign(tmp=["Col2", "Col6"]).pivot("Col1", "tmp", "Col2").merge(d))
new_df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_index(1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
```

Final output:

```
        Col1     Col2 Col3  Col4      Col5      Col6
0 2020-01-23    Joe G  USA   NaN  G5 paper    get_me
1 2020-05-01  Frank F  CAN   NaN  F4 Paper  get_me_2
```

Logic behind the `groupby` section:

- `groupby`: to pivot subset of dataframe for each date
- `d.assign(...)`: to keep the original colname `Col2` and have new column named as desired, `Col6`
- `pivot`: to unmelt the `Col2`. With `assign` and `pivot`, the subset looks like:

  ```
    tmp            Col2      Col6
    Col1                         
    2020-05-01  Frank F  get_me_2
  ```

Comment: awesome. Thanks. I just logged in and you have already got this done. Thanks.

Comment: Gotta admit that it isn't the prettiest answer i've written, but hopefully provides some insight on how to approach ;)

Comment: A few steps like groupby can be avoided. I like the way you eliminated row1 using ffill().

Comment: to delete first row, you could have just given `df = df.iloc[1:]`

Comment: Such a great answer @Chris. This is some serious pandas wizardry. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this. Your response not only helped solve my problem, but will undoubtedly help in how I approach other problems in the future. I really appreciate it.