# How to combine independent regular expressions and apply them on all rows of a dataset using Pandas?

Tags: regex, pandas

## Problem Statement:

I have two seperate regular expressions that I am trying to "combine" into one and apply to each row in a dataset. The matching part of each row should go to a new Pandas dataframe column called "Wanted". Please see example data below for how values that match should be formatted in the "Wanted" column.

### Example Data (how I want it to look):

| Column0 | Wanted (Want "Column0" to look like this) |
| --- | --- |
| Alice\t12-345-623/ 10-1234 | Alice, 12-345-623, 10-1234 |
| Bob 201-888-697 / 12-0556a | Bob, 201-888-697, 12-0556a |
| Tim 073-110-101 / 13-1290 | Tim, 073-110-101, 13-1290 |
| Joe 74-111-333/ 33-1290 and Amy(12-345-623)/10-1234c | Joe, 74-111-333, 33-1290, Amy, 12-345-623, 10-1234c |

### In other words...:

2-3 digits ----- hyphen ---- 3 digits --- hyphen ---- 3 digits ---- any character ----
2 digits --- hyphen --- 4 digits ---- permit one single character

### What I have tried #1:

- After dinking around for a while I figured out two different regular expressions that on their own will solve part of the problem. Kinda.
- This will match for the first group of numbers in each row (but doesn't get the second group--which I want) I'm interested in that I have tried. I'm not sure how robust this is though.

Example Problem Row (regex = r"(?:\d{1,3}-){0,3}\d{1,3}")

```
    search_in = "Alice\t12-345-623/ 10-1234" 
    wanted_regex = r"(?:\d{1,3}\-){0,3}\d{1,3}"
    match = re.search(wanted_regex, search_in)
    match.group(0)
```

- Wanted: Alice, 12-345-623, 10-1234
- Got: 12-345-623 # matches the group of numbers but isn't formatted how I would like (see example data)

### What I have tried #2:

- This will match for the second part in each row--- but! --- only if its the only value in the column. The problem I have is that it matches on the first group of digits instead of the second.

Example Problem Row (regex = r"(?:\d{2,3}-){1}\d{3,4}") # different regex than above!

```
    search_in = "Alice\t12-345-623/ 10-1234"
    wanted_regex = r"(?:\d{2,3}\-){1}\d{3,4}"
    match = re.search(wanted_regex, search_in)
    match.group(0)
```

- Wanted : Alice, 12-345-623, 10-1234
- Got: 12-345 # matched on the first part

### Known Problems:

- When I try, "Alice\t12-345-623/ 10-1234", it will match "12-345" when I'm trying to match "10-1234"

## Thank you!

- Thanks in advance to all you wizards being willing to help me with this problem. I really appreciate it:)
- Note: I have asked regarding regex that may make solving this problem easier. It might not, but here is the link anyways --> [How to use regex to select a row and a fixed number of rows following a row containing a specific substring in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029838/how-to-use-regex-to-select-a-row-and-a-fixed-number-of-rows-following-a-row-cont)

Comment: are you trying to `.split()` the values on multiple characters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. But no. I guess in a way the values will be split but not based on something that I can "consistently" count on each row to have like a whitespace, tab, newline, space, etc...Basically for each row--Column0 is what the data looks like and I want it to look like the "Wanted" column. Its more like extracting and formatting rather than splitting which from my understanding would require the rows to be more similar.

Answer (score 1):

So this works for the four test examples you gave. How's this using the `.split()` method? Technically this returns a *list* of values and not a string.
import re

```
# text here
text = "Joe 74-111-333/ 33-1290 and Amy(12-345-623)/10-1234c"

# split this out to a list. remove the ending parenthesis since you are *splitting* on this
new_splits = re.split(r'\t|/|and|\(| ', text.replace(')',''))

# filter out the blank spaces
list(filter(None,new_splits))

['Joe', '74-111-333', '33-1290', 'Amy', '12-345-623', '10-1234c']
```

and if you are using `pandas` you can try the same steps above:

```
df['answer_Step1'] = df['Column0'].str.split(r'\\t+|/|and|\(| ')

df['answer_final'] = df['answer_Step1'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(None,x)))
```

Comment: Phenomenal! I'm going to check to make sure this works but I definitely think it will. Thank you so much MattR I really appreciate it. I will make sure to click this as the accepted answer once I get home and can try it. Thank you soooooooooo much MattR I really, really, really appreciate it and hope you have a great rest of your day! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\s*\band\b\s*|[^\w-]+', ', ', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MJyFsH/1).

Pandas version:

```py
df['Wanted'] = df['Column0'].str.replace(r'\s*\band\b\s*|[^\w-]+', ', ', regex=True)
```

*Details*:

- `\s*\band\b\s*` - a whole word (`\b` are word boundaries) `and` enclosed with optional zero or more whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\w-]+` - one or more chars other than letters, digits, `_` and `-`

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Efhwka):

```py
import re
texts = ['Alice 12-345-623/ 10-1234',
'Bob 201-888-697 / 12-0556a','Tim 073-110-101 / 13-1290',
'Joe 74-111-333/ 33-1290 and Amy(12-345-623)/10-1234c']
for text in texts:
    print(re.sub(r'\s*\band\b\s*|[^\w-]+', ', ', text))

# => Alice, 12-345-623, 10-1234
#    Bob, 201-888-697, 12-0556a
#    Tim, 073-110-101, 13-1290
#    Joe, 74-111-333, 33-1290, Amy, 12-345-623, 10-1234c
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!! Extremely helpful response. I'm working on the solution now to see what works best. Thank you so much for being willing to help me with this it means a lot